# How can i do ROS -> Gazebo -> GUI communication

Tags: ros, gazebo, communication, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to do this kind of communication but i don't know how, there are some source codes that i can see? I know that ros can communicate with gazebo easily, but i want to return the gazebo informations to another node, as a GUI application.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194631/how-can-i-do-ros--%3E-gazebo--%3E-gui-communication/) by [GeorgeFilho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19645/georgefilho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeorgeFilho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19645/georgefilho/) on 2014-10-13**:
yes, i saw these tutorials, what i'm trying to do is control the robot on ROS by teleoperation, make the robot move on gazebo and return the robot vision in another interface created by me (Like RVIZ), i need to know how ROS and gazebo do these communications.

**Comment by [dblitz](https://answers.ros.org/users/28329/dblitz/) on 2016-10-25**:
Hey were you ever able to figure this one out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm afraid we'll need a little more detail about what you're trying to do in order to help you. Have you seen these [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=connect_ros)?

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0